# How can I override hibernate.version with Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, dependency-management

As specified in the following link, Spring Boot 3.2.1 uses Hibenate 6.4.1.Final.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.2.1/reference/html/dependency-versions.html#appendix.dependency-versions

How can I override the `hibernate.version` property of the Spring Boot with Gradle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the very same page you linked, a little further down (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.2.1/reference/html/dependency-versions.html#appendix.dependency-versions.properties) you see that you'd need to set `hibernate.version`

There is as well a link to the build tool documentation which in https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.2.1/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#managing-dependencies.dependency-management-plugin.customizing shows how to do this for gradle.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how we can do it on properties side. but I suggest you to handle it on dependencies management build.gradle file. you just need to exclude and add manually hibernate dependency with version you want.

Example with gradle kotlin:

```
//...
dependencies {
  //...
  implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa"){
    exclude(group = "org.hibernate.orm", module = "hibernate-core")
  }

  // For hibernate 6+ use group org.hibernate.orm
  implementation("org.hibernate", "hibernate-core") {
    version {
        strictly("5.6.15.Final")
    }
  }
  //...
}
/...
```

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_downgrade_and_exclude.html

Hope this could be helpful.

**UPDATED !**

Inspired by [P.J.Meisch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4393565/p-j-meisch) [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77750634/7970858); like on [this page](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.2.1/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#managing-dependencies.dependency-management-plugin.customizing), just add at the root of build.gradle file

```
//...
extra["hibernate.version"] = "6.0.0.Final" // if using kotlin gradle
//...
```

this will work if version of hibernate you want to use is up to version 6 (hibernate dependency group name has changed since v6). otherwise you will have to use the first answer for others versions.